# Without select shipping address , click on place order validation not showing Magento 2 checkout page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, validation

I have issue on place order without select shipping address or save shipping address ,click on place order validation not showing in page , showing error like below , how to handle this in Magento 2?
https://prnt.sc/13igbnk
this issue facing after add custom field in shipping address section in one page checkout.
thanks.

Comment: which payment method you are using?

Comment: stripe payment method

Comment: @GohilRajesh its stripe card method

Comment: I faced same issue and fixed some time ago.. I dont remind what exaclty I did.. I will update u once I remind it

Answer (score 0):

You can add default postcode on checkout. If your onestepcheckout has that option.